# save data to sharedPreference android and read in react native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, sharedpreferences

I have already save sharedPreference key and value in android, how i can get those sharedPreference data in react native?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dataNotifAndroid", MODE_PRIVATE);
            
            SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit(); 
            myEdit.putString("additionaldata", username);
            myEdit.apply();
```

above code is my native code in android java file, and when i run method to read sharedPreference data in android native it's ok, i got those data

```
String cookieName = sharedPreferences.getString("additionaldata", "not found");
```

when i log cookieName, it's just return true data, but when i try to read data from react native using 'react-native-sensitive-info' i cannot read the data

```
import SInfo from 'react-native-sensitive-info';

let additionalData = await SInfo.getAllItems({
        sharedPreferencesName: 'sharedPreferences',
        keychainService: '',
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, i wrong when initiate share preference name, it should be "dataNotifAndroid", case closed